# Changing or add the time to a Date in VBA

Tags: vba, date, datetime, outlook, datetime-format

I am working with a VBA project for Outlook. The project is looking at Calendar appointments and comparing them to dates pulled out of an SQL database and stored in a Date variable.

Currently when the dates come out of the SQL database they not have any Time component to them but I would like to add one to it.

For example out of the SQL query comes "07/03/2018" and I would like to be able to set this as "07/03/2018 09:00:00" and various other times of the day.

Is there a way of doing this without converting the date variable to a string and just adding the time on at the end? This is because I would like to be able to use Date based functions such as DateAdd etc. on the variable later in the program.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to add dates and times together.

Here's a few off the top of my head:

```
Sub examples()

    'store an example date
    Dim dt As Date
    dt = CDate("March 7, 2018")

    'now to add 9 hours:
    Debug.Print dt + (9 / 24)

    'or, using DateAdd:
    Debug.Print DateAdd("h", 9, dt)

    'or, add a time:
    Dim tm As Date
    tm = CDate("9:00 am")
    Debug.Print dt + tm

    'or, as text:
    Dim str As String
    str = Format(dt, "mmm d, yyyy")
    str = str & " 9:00 am"
    Debug.Print CDate(str)

    'or, with TimeValue:
    Debug.Print dt + TimeValue("9:00")

    'or, get extract the date from a datettime and add a different time:
    Debug.Print DateValue(Now()) + TimeValue("9:00")

End Sub
```

Which method is best depends on what exactly you're trying to do with it.

---

### Dates are just numbers

In Excel and VBA, dates (or DateTimes) are **just numbers** starting at:

> **Midnight on "January 0, 1900"**

...and increasing by **`1 per day`**.

```
1 = January 1, 1900, 00:00:00 (00:00 = midnight)
2 = January 2, 1900, 00:00:00

43166 = March 7, 2018
```

Need to make it 9:00 AM on Jan 2, 1900?

- 1 hour is <sup>1</sup>/<sub>24</sub>th of a day.
- ∴ `9:00 am` = `(9 ÷ 24)` = `0.375`
- ∴ `2.375` = `January 2, 1900 9:00 am`

Similarly:

- ∴ `9:00 pm` = `(18 ÷ 24)` = `0.875`
- ∴ `2.875` = `January 2, 1900 9:00 pm`

  6:00am    =   0.25   (¼ day)
  NOON      =   0.5    (½ day)
  6:00pm    =   0.75   (¾ day)

  1 hour    ≈   0.417
  1 minute  ≈   0.000695
  1 second  ≈   0.000011574

How many days until Summer?

```
Today          =   43166  (March 7, 2018)
Summer begins  =   43272  (June 21, 2018)  [Northern Hemisphere]

43272 - 43166  =   106 days
```

How many hours until Summer?

```
106 × 24       =   2544 hours
```

*...you get the picture.*  ☺

---

**Maximum time possible in Excel**:

```
Friday, December 31, 9999 23:59:59  =  2958465.99998843
```

(...so don't make any plans for that weekend.)

---

## More Information:

- Microsoft.com : [How to use dates and times in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel)
- [The Definitive Guide to Using Dates and Times in Excel](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-using-dates-times-excel/)
- Office.com : [Date and time functions (reference)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-and-time-functions-reference-fd1b5961-c1ae-4677-be58-074152f97b81)
- Stack Overflow/MSDN : [Rounding Date & Time in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155117/rounding-date-and-time-in-vba)

Comment: Thanks Ashleedawg. I didn't think that the DateAdd function would work to add hours/mins when there was no hour/min component to the date currently held.